# OneToMany relation when using custom identifier in GraphQL returns null/wrong data

Tags: symfony, graphql, doctrine, api-platform.com, symfony5

I am using [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) with Symfony 5 to build GraphQl API.

When using [custom identifier](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/) that is not a primary key, OneToMany result set returns null or wrong data. This issue is caused because when fetching data from OneToMany table, the custom identifier value is used instead of primary key.

**Example**

Table Blog has a custom identifier slug and primary key id. This table have a OneToMany relationship with Table Image

These are the queries made while fetching data:

```
SELECT b0_.id AS id_0, b0_.content AS content_1,  b0_.slug AS slug_3 FROM blog b0_ WHERE b0_.slug = "highest peak"

SELECT i0_.id AS id_0, i0_.src AS src_1 FROM image i0_ WHERE i0_.blog_id = "highest peak" ORDER BY i0_.id ASC LIMIT 30
```

While fetching from image , Blog ID should be sent in parameters but slug is used.

However, things are working fine in REST. Problem is encountered while using GraphQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to 2.5.4 from 2.5.6 fixed the problem.

**Possible Issue**

The src/Bridge/Doctrine/Orm/SubresourceDataProvider.php was updated on the version 2.5.5

Comment: Did you define ApiProperty(identifier=false) on ID and as true on your custom identifier field? Platform usually shares identifiers with doctrine if that's the case and should work if configured correctly.

Comment: @MaulikParmar Yes

Comment: Updated Issue with possible fix [#1542](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1542#issuecomment-639294405)